# Sending an email with java when a condition in arduino ide is met

Tags: java, arduino

I need to to a project for school and it requires me to send an email when the temperature sensor on my arduino reaches a certain degree. Since I am most comfortable with java I made my mail sender on java with the Java Mail API. Now I only need to connect my program in Arduino IDE and my mail sender on java so that an email is send when the temperature goes up. My code in Arduino also includes a website but that has nothing directly to do with my problem. here is my code in Arduino:

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 7    // what pin we're connected to

byte mac[] = { 0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x3A, 0xC4 };
EthernetServer server(80);



#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11



void setup() {
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }



  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {



  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
  delay(2000);

  // check if returns are valid, if they are NaN (not a number) then something went wrong!
 /* if (isnan(DHT.temperature) || isnan(DHT.humidity)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
    Serial.println(" *C");
  }*/

  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
   client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          //client.println("<script> alert('TEST'); </script>");
          // output the value of the DHT-11
         client.println("<H2>");
            client.print("Humidity: ");
            client.println("</H2>");
            client.println("<p />");
            client.println("<H1>");
            client.print(DHT.humidity);
            client.print(" %\t");
            client.println("</H1>");
            client.println("<p />"); 
            client.println("<H2>");
            client.print("Temperature: ");
            client.println("</H2>");
            client.println("<H1>");
            client.print(DHT.temperature);
            client.println("&#176;");
            client.println("C");
            client.println("</H1>");



          client.println("</html>");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call your java program. I am not familiar with arduino, can the arduino hardware run java?

Comment: the Arduino sketch runs in Arduino, not in IDE

Answer (score 0):

You Arduino sketch runs web-server. Line `Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());` prints its IP to serial interface. Your java program can make http request to this web-server and resend output via email. Or you cat send email directly from arduino via SMTP, maybe using some library like [SMTPClient](https://github.com/gregington/SMTPClient)